# modal not loading values into controls on modal

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net, ajax

I'm having an issue where my code is calling a Modal and when the modal loads and it is supposed to fill the controls on the modal with the values sent into the javascript. It loads with no errors except for the fact that all the controls are empty. I'm new to ajax and javascript so its probably somehting simple I am missing.

Thanks.

Here is my Javascript:

```
function RowClickedResults(sender, eventArgs) {
sender.get_masterTableView().fireCommand("View", eventArgs._itemIndexHierarchical);
}

    function createEditAccount(ReceivedDate, DepositedDate, tbCompanyName, tbCheckAmount, tbCheckNum, tbDesc, cbResultsBreak, cbResultAcctNum, tbResultBreak, tbResultNotes) {
    $("#EditAccount").modal('show');
    $('#EditAccount').on('load', function () {
        var rDate = $telerik.findControl(document, "rdResultReceiveDate");
        var dDate = $telerik.findControl(document, "rdResultDepositDate");
        var Comp = $telerik.findControl(document, "tbResultCompany");
        var CheckAmt = $telerik.findControl(document, "tbResultCheckAmt");
        var CheckNum = $telerik.findControl(document, "tbResultCheckNum");
        var Desc = $telerik.findControl(document, "tbResultsDesc");
        var Break = $telerik.findControl(document, "cbResultsBreak");
        var AcctNum = $telerik.findControl(document, "cbResultAcctNum");
        var BreakAmt = $telerik.findControl(document, "tbResultBreak");
        var Notes = $telerik.findControl(document, "tbResultNotes");
        rDate.set_selectedDate = ReceivedDate;
        dDate.set_selectedDate = DepositedDate;
        Comp.text = tbCompanyName;
        CheckAmt.text = tbCheckAmount;
        CheckNum.text = tbCheckNum;
        Desc.text = tbDesc;
        AcctNum.value = cbResultAcctNum;
        BreakAmt.text = tbResultBreak;
        Notes.text = tbResultNotes;
    });

}
```

here is my Modal:

```
<div id="EditAccount" class="modal fade" role="dialog">
            <div class="modal-dialog">
                <div class="modal-content">
                    <div class="modal-header">
                        <div class="row">
                            <div class="col-xs-10">
                                <h4>Edit Account Receivable</h4>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="modal-body">
                            <div class="row text-center">
                                <div>
                                    <div class="col-cx-7 text-center">
                                        <div style="padding: 5px;">
                                            <asp:Label runat="server" Text="Received Date: " />
                                            <telerik:RadDatePicker runat="server" ID="rdResultReceiveDate" Culture="en-US" />
                                        </div>
                                        <div style="padding: 5px;">
                                            <asp:Label runat="server" Text="Deposited Date: " />
                                            <telerik:RadDatePicker runat="server" ID="rdResultDepositDate" Culture="en-US" />
                                        </div>
                                        <div style="padding: 5px;">
                                            <asp:Label runat="server" Text="Company: " />
                                            <asp:TextBox runat="server" ID="tbResultCompany" />
                                        </div>
                                        <div style="padding: 5px;">
                                            <asp:Label runat="server" ID="lblResultCheck" Text="Check Amount: " />
                                            <asp:TextBox runat="server" ID="tbResultCheckAmt" />
                                        </div>
                                        <div style="padding: 5px;">
                                            <asp:Label runat="server" Text="Check Number: " />
                                            <asp:TextBox runat="server" ID="tbResultCheckNum" />
                                        </div>
                                        <div style="padding: 5px;">
                                            <asp:Label runat="server" Text="Description: " />
                                            <asp:TextBox runat="server" ID="tbResultsDesc" />
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="col-cx-7 text-center">
                                        <div style="padding: 5px;">
                                            <asp:Label runat="server" Text="Break Down: " />
                                            <telerik:RadComboBox runat="server" RenderMode="Lightweight" ID="cbResultsBreak" AutoPostBack="false"
                                                AppendDataBoundItems="true" CloseDropDownOnBlur="true" DropDownAutoWidth="Enabled"
                                                ShowDropDownOnTextboxClick="true" Enabled="true" OnSelectedIndexChanged="BreakDownSelectedIndexChanged">
                                            </telerik:RadComboBox>
                                        </div>
                                        <div style="padding: 5px;">
                                            <asp:Label runat="server" Text="Account Number: " />
                                            <telerik:RadComboBox runat="server" RenderMode="Lightweight" ID="cbResultAcctNum" AutoPostBack="false"
                                                AppendDataBoundItems="true" CloseDropDownOnBlur="true" DropDownAutoWidth="Enabled"
                                                ShowDropDownOnTextboxClick="true" Enabled="true">
                                            </telerik:RadComboBox>
                                        </div>
                                        <div style="padding: 5px;">
                                            <asp:Label runat="server" Text="Break Down: " />
                                            <asp:TextBox runat="server" ID="tbResultBreak" />
                                        </div>
                                        <div style="padding: 5px;">
                                            <asp:Label runat="server" Text="Notes(Optional): " />
                                            <asp:TextBox runat="server" ID="tbResultNotes" />
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="modal-footer">
                            <div class="row">
                                <div class="col-xs-6 text-right">
                                    <asp:LinkButton runat="server" ID="btnEditSave" CssClass="btn btn-success" OnClientClick="saveEditAccount(this); return false;" OnClick="btnSaveEdit_Click">Save</asp:LinkButton>
                                </div>
                                <div class="col-xs-6 text-left">
                                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger" data-dismiss="modal">Cancel</button>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <telerik:RadWindowManager RenderMode="Lightweight" ID="RadWindowManager2" runat="server" />
        </div>
```

Here is where my javascript is called :

```
<telerik:RadGrid ID="rgResults" runat="server" FooterStyle-ForeColor="#BA1A8B"
                            HeaderStyle-BackColor="#39ac99"
                            HeaderStyle-Font-Bold="true" AlternatingRowStyle-BackColor="White"
                            AllowPaging="true" PageSize="10"
                            OnItemCommand="rgResults_ItemCommand"
                            OnNeedDataSource="rgResults_NeedDataSource"
                            OnItemDataBound="rgResults_ItemDataBound"
                            OnPreRender="rgResults_PreRender"
                            AutoGenerateColumns="false">
                            <ClientSettings AllowKeyboardNavigation="true" EnablePostBackOnRowClick="false">
                                <Selecting AllowRowSelect="true"></Selecting>
                                <ClientEvents OnRowClick="RowClickedResults" />
                            </ClientSettings>
                            <MasterTableView DataKeyNames="Deposited_Date">
                                <Columns>
                                    <telerik:GridTemplateColumn UniqueName="commandColumn">
                                        <ItemTemplate>
                                            <telerik:RadImageButton ID="btnDelete" runat="server" CommandName="Delete" ImageUrl="~/Content/Images/delete.gif" />
                                        </ItemTemplate>
                                    </telerik:GridTemplateColumn>
                                    <telerik:GridBoundColumn HeaderText="Deposit Date" DataField="Deposited_Date" UniqueName="Deposited_Date" />
                                    <telerik:GridBoundColumn HeaderText="Company Name" DataField="Company_Name" UniqueName="Company_Name" />
                                </Columns>
                            </MasterTableView>
                            <PagerStyle Mode="NextPrevAndNumeric"></PagerStyle>
                        </telerik:RadGrid>
```

Here is my code behind:

```
case "View":
                {

                    foreach (GridDataItem item in rgResults.Items)
                    {
                        string Deposit = item.GetDataKeyValue("Deposited_Date").ToString();
                        ar = ydb.Accounts_Receivable.ToList().Where(t => t.Deposited_Date == DateTime.Parse(Deposit)).ToList();
                        foreach (Accounts_Receivable ar2 in ar.ToList())
                        {
                            if (SearchByDate.SelectedDate.Value.ToString() == Deposit)
                            {
                                if (ar2.Posted_Date == null)
                                {
                                    Accounts_Receivable_Breakdown arb = ar2.Accounts_Receivable_Breakdown.ToList().Where(t => t.Accounts_Receivable_ID == ar2.Accounts_Receivable_ID).First();
                                    ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(this, GetType(), Guid.NewGuid().ToString(), "createEditAccount(\"" + ar2.Received_Date.Value.ToString() + "\",\"" + ar2.Deposited_Date.ToString() + "\",\"" +
                                        ar2.Company_Name + "\",\"" + ar2.Check_Amount + "\",\"" + ar2.Check_Number + "\",\"" +
                                         ar2.Description_ + "\",\"" + arb.Breakdown_Amount +
                                         "\",\"" + arb.Account_Number + "\",\"" + arb.Breakdown_Amount + "\",\"" + arb.Notes + "\");", true);
                                }
                                else
                                {
                                    rdResultReceiveDate.Enabled = false;
                                    rdResultReceiveDate.Enabled = false;
                                    tbResultCompany.ReadOnly = true;
                                    tbResultCheckAmt.ReadOnly = true;
                                    tbResultCheckNum.ReadOnly = true;
                                    tbResultsDesc.ReadOnly = true;
                                    cbResultAcctNum.Enabled = false;
                                    Accounts_Receivable_Breakdown arb = ar2.Accounts_Receivable_Breakdown.ToList().Where(t => t.Accounts_Receivable_ID == ar2.Accounts_Receivable_ID).First();
                                    ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(this, GetType(), Guid.NewGuid().ToString(), "createEditAccount(\"" + Eval("ar2.Received_Date.Value").ToString() + "\",\"" + Eval("ar2.Deposited_Date").ToString() + "\",\"" +
                                        Eval("ar2.Company_Name") + "\",\"" + Eval("ar2.Check_Amount") + "\",\"" + Eval("ar2.Check_Number") + "\",\"" +
                                         Eval("ar2.Description_") + "\",\"" + Eval("arb.Breakdown_Amount") +
                                         "\",\"" + Eval("arb.Account_Number") + "\",\"" + Eval("arb.Breakdown_Amount") + "\",\"" + Eval("arb.Notes") + "\");", true);
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }

                    break;
                }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured out the issue. The code had to do a postback since I touched the serverside code and the modal was inside of my updatepanel. Moving the modal out of the update panel let the code finish the postback before trying to find the controls and set the data to them.